# RDTSCP and Instruction order

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, osdev

I'm using the `rdtscp` instruction to read the `ecx` register for detecting cpu and numa node ids (I'm developing an os).

The code looks like the following

```
inline static long get(unsigned char *node_id = 0, unsigned char *cpu_id = 0)
{
    unsigned int p;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtscp\n" : "=c" (p) : : "memory");

    if (node_id) {
        *node_id = p >> 12;
    }

    if (cpu_id) {
        *cpu_id = p & 0xfff;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On using this function, I have a not understandable behaviour: The CPU tells me a lot of exceptions (page fault, general protection fault, ...). That indicates to me, that the cpu or node id is not read, but if I log the id, all seems right and no exception appears.

So in code:

```
// ...
unsigned char cpu, numa;
get(&numa, &cpu);
// use cpu and numa id creates exception
```

but

```
// ...
unsigned char cpu, numa;
get(&numa, &cpu);
print(cpu); // <--- this makes cpu reading ok?
// use cpu and numa id is ok
```

Is the cpu reordering my instructions, so that he will use cpu_id/numa_id before reading it?

Comment: it seems like you don't tell the compiler that eax and edx are clobbered as well.

Comment: yeah, thanks, that fixed it!

Comment: let me quickly write an answer.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell the compiler that the registers eax and edx are clobbered. Add them to the [clobbered list](https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3):

```
__asm__ __volatile__("rdtscp\n" : "=c" (p) : : "memory", "eax", "edx");
```

Comment: Why do you clobber "memory" here? This instruction does not clobber memory. And I guess you are assuming here that the Intel dialect has been specified (`-masm=intel`); probably worth calling out explicitly, as this won't work otherwise.